# How do you substitue a Python capture followed by a number character?

Tags: python, regex, string

When using [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), how to you handle a situation where you need a capture followed by a number in the replacement string? For example, you cannot use "\10" for capture 1 followed by a '0' character because it will be interpreted as capture 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\g<1>0
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

> \g<number> uses the corresponding
>   group number; \g<2> is therefore
>   equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous
>   in a replacement such as \g<2>0. \20
>   would be interpreted as a reference to
>   group 20, not a reference to group 2
>   followed by the literal character '0'.